# Starting up a screen (unix command) + running a command in 1 command?

Tags: unix, command-line, gnu-screen

Was wondering how I can start up a command such as:

```
while :; do ./myCommand; done;
```

But instead of doing the usual

```
screen -S nameOfMyScreen
```

Then the command

```
while :; do ./myCommand; done;
```

Then detach the screen

```
^a ^d (Control "a" the control "d"
```

I would like it to start and detach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
screen -d -m sh -c "while :; do ./myCommand; done;"
```

Explanation:

- `-d -m` starts screen in detached mode (create session but don't attach to it)
- `sh -c commandline` starts a shell which executes the given command line (necessary, since you are using the `while` builtin).

Comment: The version of screen on my system says that the -c option is to read an alternate config file instead of .screenrc.

Comment: The `-c` is not passed to screen but rather to `sh`. After the screen command line parser reads `sh` (i.e. something without a dash), it know that no more options follow and that everything else is a command that should be executed.

Comment: thanks for the shell trick. I was originally invoking a command, but I wanted to `tee` the output to a log file including stderr... when I added the pipe and redirection the log would be empty,probably getting the output from `screen` instead of my command. I tried adding quotes to no success. Using a subshell as suggested here worked great! \o/

Answer (score 3):

From `screen -h`, these look useful:

```
-dmS name     Start as daemon: Screen session in detached mode.
-X            Execute <cmd> as a screen command in the specified session.
```

I haven't done this myself, but that's where I'd start.

***Update:***

The top of the help also says

```
Use: path/to/screen [-opts] [cmd [args]]
```

so the `-X` switch may be to execute a *screen* command as opposed to a *shell* command. You might just be able to put your command after the `-dmS <name>` without any `-X` switch.

Comment: +1. A combination of these will do your job. Since your *command* is a script, you might have to either put it in a file and pass that or use `bash -c` or something similar.